# What is bias voltage and what is it's function in a Scan Tunneling Microscope?

Tags: voltage, microscopy

I was reading about the Scan Tunneling Microscope and I read that a 'bias voltage' is needed to realize a current of electrons between the needle and the sample.
I don't know what the definition of 'bias voltage' is in this case, I thought it was the voltage of the base of a transistor..

Comment: Did you read the [Wikipedia article on biasing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biasing)?

Comment: Yeah, I know it's the DC voltage to operate correctly, but I don't see the link with a microscope

Comment: If there weren't a voltage between needle and sample, you wouldn't get electrons flowing from one to the other, would you?

Comment: @ACuriousMind I think you mean no mean electron flow, because if the needle and the sample are close enough electrons can be exchanged, independent of the voltage, however the average flow of electrons will be zero.

Comment: Yeah, I know what voltage means, but not what 'bias' voltage is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a STM, you find the distance between the (atomically sharp) scanning tip and the surface at which tunneling starts to occur - that is, electrons "jump" the gap between the two and a current flows.

How much current flows depends on the size of the gap, and the voltage between them. If you have no voltage, no current will flow regardless of the gap. If the voltage is too high, you won't be able to resolve small distances (since the current will be almost independent of distance). There is a sweet spot where you will see a significant change in current with distance. That is the voltage difference you need to apply between the tip and the sample - the bias voltage.